# Why EF code first update method does not work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, updates

I have this method :

```
public void Update(DBS.BankAccount entity)
{
    try
    {
        using (var _nahidContext = new NahidContext())
        {
            _nahidContext.BankAccounts.Attach(entity);
            var bankAccountElement = _nahidContext.Entry(entity);
            bankAccountElement.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            _nahidContext.SaveChanges();
            //__________  or   ___________
            //var bankAccountElement = FindById(entity.Id);
            //if (_nahidContext.Entry(bankAccountElement).State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
            //{
            //    _nahidContext.BankAccounts.Attach(bankAccountElement);
            //}
            ////_nahidContext.Entry(bankAccountElement).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            //_nahidContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Which run without any error but my `bankAccountElement` does not change.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

First you attach (entity state= unchanged), then you set values with same values than attached entity, so it keeps unchanged.

You should do this

```
    _nahidContext.BankAccounts.Attach(entity);
    var bankAccountElement = _nahidContext.Entry(entity);
    bankAccountElement.State = EntityState.Modified;
```

You can read more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)